# Linear Stability Analysis question on if x should be treated as a function of t?

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I am reading about linear stability analysis and have gotten stuck on some of the notation. For example, the book discusses finding the stability of the fixed points for x' = sinx. The book determines that f'(x) = cos(x). However, I thought that x' = sinx was equivalent to dx/dt = sinx where x is some function of t. Therefore wouldn't f'(x) be cosx * dx/dt = cosx*sinx? Where is my logic going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I think in the proof it looks like f'(x) is only used to represent the Taylor expansion of x' = f(x). That would then make sense why it only relies on x and is not a function of t and the use of f(x) notation.